# SharePoint 2013 Warm up script for Claims Provider

Tags: 2013, claims-based-auth, warm-up

I tried this [blog](https://sharepointobservations.wordpress.com/2014/02/21/sharepoint-2013-warm-up-script/) but I get and error with

> "Invoke-WebRequest : Invalid Uri. The host name could not be parsed."

Can anybody help me resolve this issue?

Comment: try this one: https://spbestwarmup.codeplex.com/